# Sequelize.js can't generate condition in WHERE clause for associated table field

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have below code in Node.js with sequelize.js module

```
// association Users belongs to Companies
Users.belongsTo(Companies, {
    foreignKey: 'company_id',
});

// default conditions
var conditions = {deleted: '0'};
var companyConditions = {deleted: '0'};

// custom conditions parameters
conditions['$or'] = {first_name: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'}, last_name: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'}, email: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'}};
companyConditions['$or'] = {name: {'$like': req.query.search + '%'}};

// generrate select query
Users.findAll({include: [{model: Companies, where: companyConditions}], where: conditions});
```

**But it produce different query than want to achieve**

```
SELECT `users`.*, `company`.* FROM `users` AS `users` 
INNER JOIN `companies` AS `company` ON `users`.`company_id` = `company`.`id` AND `company`.`deleted` = '0' AND (`company`.`name` LIKE 'town%') 
WHERE `users`.`deleted` = '0' AND (`users`.`first_name` LIKE '%town%' OR `users`.`last_name` LIKE '%town%' OR `users`.`email` LIKE '%town%');
```

If I change custom condition `its not working`

```
// custom conditions parameters
conditions['$or'] = {'company.name': {'$like': req.query.search + '%'},first_name: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'}, last_name: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'}, email: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'}};
 //   companyConditions['$or'] = {name: {'$like': req.query.search + '%'}};
```

Then node.js throws error `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'users.company.name' in 'where clause'`

**What I want to achieve?**

```
SELECT users.*, company.* FROM users AS users 
INNER JOIN companies AS company 
ON users.company_id = company.id AND company.deleted = '0' 
WHERE users.deleted = '0' AND (users.first_name LIKE '%town%' OR users.last_name LIKE '%town%' OR users.email LIKE '%town%' OR company.name LIKE 'town%');
```

Any one have any idea about this? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap column name in main where with `$` symbol, that allows to do query to columns in include

```
// custom conditions parameters
conditions['$or'] = {'$company.name$': {'$like': req.query.search + '%'}, first_name: {'$like': '%' + req.query.search + '%'},...
```